# Can a non-regular language $L$ have a non regular $L^*$?

Tags: regular-languages, regular-expressions, pumping-lemma

I have been looking around and i cant seem to find an example of such case that a non-regular $L$ has a non regular $L^*$. Is it possible? If so, can you provide an example of such case please?

Comment: Do you know any non regular language $L$? Have you tried with one of them?

Comment: I do, for example, L = {a^nb^n | n e N}. I have tried but am still having troubles with this topic.

Comment: I am sure that you can succeed in proving that for this language, $L^*$ is not regular, since the **same** usual proof (with pumping lemma) works.

Comment: Thank you guys so much!

Comment: For your information: if $L$ is a language over a single letter alphabet, then $L^*$ is always regular, whetever the complexity of $L$. But that is a special case of course.

Answer (score 4):

Take the [Dyck language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dyck_language) $D$. It is context-free but not regular and satisfies $D^* = D$.